# install bowtie2 from sources cannot find -ltbb

Tags: software-installation, bowtie2

I am trying to install bowtie2 aligner from sources without the root access.
Bowtie2 needs tbb package to be installed and it is recommended to install oneTBB.

```
# install one TBB
mkdir -p SHOME/soft
cd $HOME/soft
git clone https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneTBB.git
cd oneTBB
make
```

Then I add C_INCLUDE_PATH to .bashrc:

```
echo "export C_INCLUDE_PATH=$HOME/soft/oneTBB/include" >> ~./bashrc
```

and continue to install bowtie2:

```
# install bowtie2
mkdir -p $HOME/soft/bowtie/source
cd $HOME/soft/bowtie/source
wget https://sourceforge.net/projects/bowtie-bio/files/bowtie2/2.4.1/bowtie2-2.4.1-source.zip
unzip bowtie2-2.4.1-source.zip -d ..
cd ../bowtie2-2.4.1
make
```

TBB library is recognized but in the end I get this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltbb
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltbbmalloc_proxy
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

ltbb and ltbballoc_proxy are not in TBB but libtbb and libtbballoc_proxy instead.
I also tryed to add variables to .bashrc:

```
TBB_LIB_PATH=$HOME/soft/oneTBB
TBB_INCLUDE_PATH=$HOME/soft/oneTBB/include
TBB_RELEASE_DIR=$HOME/soft/oneTBB/build/home/suvar/apps/oneTBB/build/linux_intel64_gcc_cc9.3.0_libc2.31_kernel5.4.0_release
```

but seems it does not help.

I need help to complete the installation of bowtie2 on our server.

Comment: Did you remember to source your bashrc before compiling?

Comment: sure: source ~./bashrc

Comment: Do you really need to compile Bowtie2? There are compiled binaries for Linux and MaxOsX available:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/bowtie-bio/files/bowtie2/2.4.1/bowtie2-2.4.1-linux-x86_64.zip
https://sourceforge.net/projects/bowtie-bio/files/bowtie2/2.4.1/bowtie2-2.4.1-macos-x86_64.zip

Comment: If you are using Ubuntu you can install tbb with `sudo apt install libtbb-dev`, in MacOS you can install it with Homebrew `brew install tbb`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the path to the source files for the compiler *and* the full path to the compiled libraries (all parent directories included) for the linker.  You also need to use either CPATH or CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH instead of C_INCLUDE_PATH to point to the oneTBB source, since bowtie2 is C++ and C_INCLUDE_PATH will only have an effect for C (see [Environment Variables Affecting GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Environment-Variables.html) in the GCC documentation for more info.)

For example like this, inside bowtie2-2.4.1, without making any lasting changes to the shell's setup in this case:

```
$ ONETBB=$HOME/soft/oneTBB
$ export LIBRARY_PATH=$ONETBB/build/linux_intel64_gcc_cc5.4.0_libc2.23_kernel4.4.0_release
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH
$ export CPATH=$ONETBB/include
$ make
```

After it's built you'll still need the library path to oneTBB defined (via LD_LIBRARY_PATH) so bowtie2 can find it at run-time.

**But if you don't have a specific reason to compile from source I'd recommend avoiding it.**  You could go with what h.mon suggested and use an existing binary, or use a package manger to install it like zorbax suggested.  [Conda](https://conda.io/) has [a package for bowtie2 in the bioconda channel](https://anaconda.org/bioconda/bowtie2), up through and beyond version 2.4.1, and you can use that as a package manager without root access.